# R terra::mask report error ‘Error: [mask] extents do not match’

Tags: raster, r, extract-by-mask, terra

I have a temperature tif, and I want to extract my study area.But it reports that `extents do not match`. I want to know how to fix it and why the extents do not match?

I think `to_be_masked` raster's extrents is larger than `model_raster`'s extrents.

```
> model_raster <- rast("E:/GIMMS/01.data/wgs1982.tif")
> model_raster
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 405, 566, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 106.2017, 110.9184, 36.81786, 40.19286  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : wgssos1982.tif 
name        : 1982sos_season1_output 
min value   :               80.00426 
max value   :              128.40460 
> 
> to_be_masked <- rast("E:/GIMMS/01.data/tmp1/1982_tmp_01.tif")
> to_be_masked
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4717, 7680, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 72.19605, 136.196, 16.25046, 55.55879  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : 1982_tmp_01.tif 
name        : tmp_1 
min value   :  -413 
max value   :   234 
> 
> test <- to_be_masked %>% mask(model_raster)
Error: [mask] extents do not match
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extents do not match because they are different:

```
extent      : 106.2017, 110.9184, 36.81786, 40.19286  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
extent      : 72.19605, 136.196, 16.25046, 55.55879  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

To do a `mask` operation you need pixels that line up perfectly in order to mask out `NA` cells from the mask into the masked raster, so you need two rasters with the same extent and resolution.

In some cases you can `crop` the large raster to the small raster:

```
cropped = crop(to_be_masked, model_raster)
```

but this doesn't help with your data because the rasters still don't have the same extents:

```
> ext(cropped)
SpatExtent : 106.204356764323, 110.921019746094, 36.8171249226203, 40.1921246364215 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> ext(model_raster)
SpatExtent : 106.2017, 110.9184, 36.81786, 40.19286 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

...**because the pixels don't line up**. This can be seen in a difference in the `origin` of the rasters, the point where (if the grids were to be expanded west and south) the nearest point to (0,0) would be found:

```
> origin(model_raster)
[1] 0.000949470 0.001193333
> origin(to_be_masked)
[1] -0.003893594  0.000461378
```

So these grids don't line up. So you can't mask one with the other as is.

One solution then is to resample the mask layer to the same coordinate system as the layer to mask:

```
resmask = resample(to_be_masked, model_raster)
```

now you have a mask layer that is interpolated to a new grid system, so watch out for artefacts induced by interpolation.

That done, you can mask:

```
masked = mask(model_raster, resmask)
```